# PHP page visit logger

Tags: php

So I wanted to make something like a counter for visits for every page **AND** directory. The purpose was that of a security perspective but so far I've only managed to think of this:

```
<?php

include('connect.php');
$date = date("d.m.Y H:i:s",time());
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$query = "INSERT INTO `visits` VALUES ('','$date','$url','$ip')";

mysql_query($query);

?>
```

Problem is that in order for this to work I need to include this snippet in each file which isn't exactly what I need since, for example, I can't include it in any of my files in the `/js/` folder. How can I make use of something like this and log each visit on each page individually?

Comment: (This is a terrible idea).

Comment: For starters, if you did end up doing this, you would be executing a query for every single file that is embedded on a page.

Comment: cause if you have high traffic you will be hitting millions of rows within no time

Comment: Also, [please read this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1) before you continue.

Comment: have you thought about putting it in a file and just including the file in all your pages?

Comment: Perhaps I should've mentioned that I'll be having the database on a separate VPS. But nonetheless, I won't be really experiencing enough traffic to cause trouble.

Comment: @Marty how is he going to get client sql injection using server generated vars?

Comment: I suppose request uri could contain injection. good point.

Comment: @dewd That's not the point - you shouldn't be in the habit of building queries like this in the first place.

Comment: @Marty, I already have a WAF for almost all kinds of web-based attacks. I'm asking about something else.

Comment: Just the fact that you're using a deprecated API really doesn't convince me that you're safe against attacks.

Comment: @schmitz sql injection is where the variables you include in an sql statement can be used to inject unwanted sql into your db. since i might find out you're using the request url var, i could add sql to the uri, thus changing your statement - potentially very dramatically. always use prepared statements just in case.

Answer (score 1):

If you have common scripts for every page you should start thinking about a landing page which is actualy delivering the content to the users request. This could be your index.php and your pages are accessed by an page-id (for example /index.php?show=home) or use a url-rewrite engine from the webserver to rewrite www.yourdomain.de/home to index.php?show=home so every page request starts at index.php and you can track the visitor and the requested page from the "show"-parameter. So you don't have lots of php files but only one for start and load the desired content from this starting point.

So first thing to do would be to reorganize your page to a single landing page with commonly executed scripts (like session handling, tracking, logging etc).

Comment: Note this is called the [front controller pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern).